# Laravel 5.2 Eloquent Relationships with Irregular Names

Tags: sql, orm, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm building out my first project in Laravel and have run into a bit of a snag with a one to many relationship between two tables.

Historically, I would have done something like this in SQL to achieve my end goal:

```
SELECT tag_key.key
FROM tag
LEFT JOIN tag_key
ON tag.tag_key_id = tag_key.id;
```

With Laravel, I'm trying to do things the ORM way and am getting hung up, probably on a naming thing somewhere down the pipe. Here's the code:

**Part 1: Migrations:**

"tag_keys" table

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTagKeysTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tag_keys', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('key', 128);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('tag_keys');
    }
}
```

"tags" table

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTagsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('value', 128);

            $table->integer('tag_key_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('tag_key_id')->references('id')->on('tag_keys')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('tags');
    }
}
```

**Part 2: Models:**

"TagKey" model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TagKey extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'key'
    ];

    protected $dates = [];

    protected $table = 'tag_keys';

    /**
     * Tag Keys have many Tags
     */
    public function values()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Tag');
    }
}
```

"Tag" model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'value',
        'tag_key_id'
    ];

    protected $dates = [];

    /**
     * Tag values belong to Tag Keys
     */
    public function key()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\TagKey');
    }
}
```

Independently, they both work just fine. However, when I jump into tinker and try this (given there is a valid row in both the "tag" and "tag_key" tables and given that id 1 in the "tag" has the value of 1 in the "tag_key" table under the "tag_key_id" column):

```
$tag = App\Tag::first();
$tag->key;

=> null
```

What am I missing here? How do I build this association?

Comment: Have you checked laravel docs? There are some examples on how to define many-to-many relation and it's not the way you're doing that - https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo, thanks for the pointer. This is actually a one to many relationship, so the many to many doc isn't really applicable here. Care to be my second set of eyes and help me debug the issue? Fundamentally, I think it's got to do with mixing camel and snake cases. Changing database naming up is my next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the foreign key name doesn't follow Eloquent conventions ("snake case" name of the owning model and suffix it with _id), you should specify it in the relationship:

TagKey object:

`return $this->hasMany('App\Tag', 'tag_key_id');`

Key object:

`return $this->belongsTo('App\TagKey', 'tag_key_id');`

More info [in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)